# Save excel as PDF in specific location

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following line of code which is supposed to take an excel spreadsheet, and save it as a PDF file.

It was working correctly and saving the PDF files in the same directory that the file was opened in, but suddenly it does not seem to be saving the PDF files in the right place.

Sometimes it saves it and sometimes it does not. Is there a way I can update my code to include a specific location or the location that the file was opened in?

```
Sheets("Mortgage Charts").Activate
Range("L2").Select
With Sheets("Mortgage Charts")
    .ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="Mortgage Scorecard " & Format(.Range("L2"), "mm-dd-yyyy"), _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
End With
```

Comment: I would also suggest trying to avoid `Activate` and `Select` if possible (just to form good coding habits). I've always found [this post useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) in how to be explicit in different situations.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by changing the `OpenAfterPublish:=` from `false` to `true`. Then look at the document properties when its open to find out where it is saving.

I would imagine if there are no errors, it is saving to an unknown folder. If you find the file is indeed saving, I would add the directory name to the `Filename:=` argument. You can also set the filepath to a variable with

```
x = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
```

it will return the path of your workbook as a string.

Comment: Can i suggest editing `Applicaiton.Activeworkbook.Path` in case anyone decides to copy and paste ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using what John suggested in your code.

```
Dim thisPath As String, docName As String

thisPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
docName = thisPath & "\Mortgage Scorecard " & Format(Range("L2"), "mm-dd-yyyy")

Sheets("Mortgage Charts").Activate
Range("L2").Select
With Sheets("Mortgage Charts")
    .ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=docName, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
End With
```

EDIT

If you want to open the PDF after saving, add this after `End With`:

```
openDoc = docName & ".pdf"
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink openDoc
```